# Show matching nested child divs based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, I am new to JQuery and I have found posts answering to similar question but not helpful in my case. I am trying to get all matched divs containing dropdown selected value similar to [this](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-select-box).

**HTML -- JQuery code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $("#product_box .overflow-hidden p").each(function() {
          $(this).not("p:contains(" + optionValue + ")").hide();
        });
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $("#product_box .overflow-hidden p").show();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Choose following</option>
    <option value="Bestron">Bestron</option>
    <option value="Hanseatic">Hanseatic</option>
    <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="AEG">AEG</option>
    <option value="Gorenje">Gorenje</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="row" id="product_box">
  <h4 class="mt-0 mb-2 header-title col-md-12">
    Products
  </h4>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body overflow-hidden" id="Bestron">
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Bestron</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Klimagerät</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">A</span></p>

          <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Hanseatic</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Backofen</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>



          <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

      <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123 Frontlader</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

        <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end col -->
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

    <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">AEG</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

      <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end col -->
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
    <div class="media">

      <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123 Frontlader</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">C</span></p>
        <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end col -->
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

    <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Side by side Kühlschrank</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">52232548</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">117392336</span></strong></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

      <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am sorry if my question posting method does not fulfill the standards of respective portal.

Comment: From what I can tell, you have `$("#product_box .overflow-hidden p")` but the last 3 items aren't inside `#product_box` so they're not affected.

Comment: I suggest starting with simpler html (or a bit of css) so you can see what's happening a bit clearer.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want to hide and when.  From the description/dropdown, I would suggest that you want to hide `col-xl-3` as that's the outer div of each "card".  Give that div a `data-manufacturer=` and then find/hide based on the data- attribute (or use a class if you prefer/find it easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  I've used your code, but added some modifications. You have to search through the elements correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".card-box").parent().each(function() {
          $(this).not(':contains('+ optionValue +')').hide();
          $(':contains('+ optionValue +')').show();
        });
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(".card-box").parent().show();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Choose following</option>
    <option value="Bestron">Bestron</option>
    <option value="Hanseatic">Hanseatic</option>
    <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="AEG">AEG</option>
    <option value="Gorenje">Gorenje</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="row" id="product_box">
  <h4 class="mt-0 mb-2 header-title col-md-12">
    Products
  </h4>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body overflow-hidden" id="Bestron">
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Bestron</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Klimagerät</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">A</span></p>

          <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Hanseatic</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Backofen</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>



          <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

      <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123 Frontlader</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

        <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end col -->
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

    <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">AEG</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

      <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end col -->
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
    <div class="media">

      <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123 Frontlader</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">C</span></p>
        <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end col -->
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

    <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Side by side Kühlschrank</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">52232548</span></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">117392336</span></strong></p>
      <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

      <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but the problem is I can't add the class 'card-container' as you did because I am applying this script to DOM elements directly. Is there another way to do the same? Thank you once again!

Comment: @FelixTenn, no problem, easy-peasy.  I've updated the code to look for the parent of `.card-box`.  If it works for you please upvote and mark as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can give each "box" a `data-manufacture` (or `data-manu` for short), eg `data-manu='samsung'` then you can hide all of them in one go using `[data-x]` selector:

```
$("#product_box [data-manu]").hide();
```

and show the one that matches the `select` with `[data-x="value"]` selector

```
$("#product_box [data-manu='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
```

(where `this` is the `select`)

Some of the original HTML didn't quite match, so I've move all the "cards" into the "product_box" so that they show/hide correctly, giving a much simplified:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $("#product_box [data-manu]").hide();
    $("#product_box [data-manu='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Choose following</option>
    <option value="bestron">Bestron</option>
    <option value="hanseatic">Hanseatic</option>
    <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="aeg">AEG</option>
    <option value="gorenje">Gorenje</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="row" id="product_box">
  <h4 class="mt-0 mb-2 header-title col-md-12">
    Products
  </h4>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6" data-manu="bestron">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body overflow-hidden" id="Bestron">
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Bestron</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Klimagerät</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">A</span></p>

          <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6" data-manu="hanseatic">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Hanseatic</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Backofen</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>



          <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6" data-manu="samsung">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

      <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123 Frontlader</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

        <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6" data-manu="aeg">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

      <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">AEG</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

        <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6" data-manu="samsung">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">123 Frontlader</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">123</span></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">123</span></strong></p>
          <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">C</span></p>
          <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6" data-manu="samsung">
    <div class="card-box widget-user" style="padding:1rem!important;">

      <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Brands :</strong><span class="ml-2">Samsung</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Group :</strong><span class="ml-2">Side by side Kühlschrank</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Article No. :</strong><span class="ml-2">52232548</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Lager:<span class="ml-2">117392336</span></strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted font-13 my-0"><strong>Grade :</strong><span class="ml-2">B</span></p>

        <hr style="height: 1px;background:#e8e8e8;" class="my-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

If you're unable to change the HTML (eg provided by a 3rd party service) then I suggest a "pre-run" to add the required data- attribute as a one-off in your doc.ready.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but the problem is I can't add the class 'card-container' as you did because I am applying this script to DOM elements directly. Is there another way to do the same? Thank you once again!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "apply this script to DOM elements directly".  I've not used "card-container" anywhere.